Why some authors interpret the action in the Euclidean signature as a measure of entropy?
In discussions of the black hole information paradox, I've encountered literature suggesting that some authors interpret the action in the Euclidean signature as a measure of entropy. Could you elaborate on this concept?

Could you perhaps reference any of that literature or at least name these "some authors"? The more precise your explanation of what your question is about is, the better your chance at getting good answers.

The path integral in Euclidean signature takes the (schematic) form $$Z = \int Dg e^{-I}$$ where $I$ is the Euclidean action $$I[g] = \frac{1}{16\pi G_N} \int d^n x \sqrt{g} R\,.$$ This looks an awful lot like a partition function in statistical mechanics, and in the canonical ensemble, $S= \ln Z - \beta E$. Black holes have a fixed mass and therefore a fixed temperature $T_H$, so the canonical ensemble is appropriate. In the classical limit, we can approximate $\ln Z \approx -I_E$, where now I mean the minimal value of the on-shell Euclidean action. This already shows there is gonna be a relationship between the action and the entropy. Slightly worried I messed up a sign somewhere but I'll ignore that for now.
Because of diffeomorphism invariance, the on shell action has two pieces: the part at the horizon, and the part at infinity. Essentially, the part at infinity cancels the $\beta E$ part (it basically is just the ADM Hamiltonian) and the remaining part at the horizon is just the usual Bekenstein-Hawking area term when the action is given by the Einstein-Hilbert term. More generally, this is the Wald entropy.
So the connection between the action and the entropy comes from the connection between the path integral and the usual partition function of thermodynamics. That's a deep property of QFT which has many avatars. Gravity is not a QFT, but at low enough energies it approximately is (it's an effective field theory). So as long as you can control the path integral with a reasonable semiclassical approximation, you're okay to treat this as a derivation of the black hole entropy.

Thank you for the clear explanation. I have a follow-up question regarding the on-shell action of a scalar field in a gravitational field. Can we interpret the on-shell action as the sum of the entropy associated with the scalar field and the entropy related to the classical gravitational configuration? In this case, would this be equivalent to the semi-classical entropy of the fields?

Being super rough, you can think of the entropy as $S=-\sum_i p_i \ln p_i$. The path integral, like the partition function, computes the probabilities $p_i$ of being in various states when you take the right derivatives to isolate different $i$. If you assume $p_i$ is dominated by a single $i$ and take the right derivatives, you'll find the results youre looking for. It turns out it's not exactly the on-shell action but a certain derivative of it which becomes the entropy: this is computed using the "replica trick" if you want to learn more. You can use holography to make all this more legit

Can you write down what $I$ is? It is a function of which quantities?

Added it in an edit
